# OpenCV.js side-effect: video is being pushed into new empty matrix without being requested

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am trying to debug a problem I'm having with OpenCV.js. I am trying to create a simple circle-finding function, but my video feed is being displayed in my canvas. I've boiled it down to the smallest set that shows the issue.

What makes no sense is that I create a new, empty matrix and display it, and I see my video feed in it.

1. I start with the typical way of detecting circles: Stream the video into matrix `scrMat`, convert `srcMat` into a grayscale `grayMat`, and then call `HoughCircles` to detect circles from `grayMat` into `circlesMat`.
2. Then, independently, I create a new `displayMat` and display it.
3. I see the output below, where the right-handside is `displayMat`.

[image]

Somehow `displayMat` is being filled. The effect goes away if I comment out the `HoughCircles` line.

How is this happening?

```
const cv = require('opencv.js');  // v1.2.1

const video = document.getElementById('video');
const width = 300;
const height = 225;
const FPS = 30;
let stream;

let srcMat = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let grayMat = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC1);
let circlesMat = new cv.Mat();

const cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

export default function capture() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
  .then(_stream => {
      stream = _stream;
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.play();
      setTimeout(processVideo, 0)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(`An error occurred: ${err}`));

  function processVideo () {
    const begin = Date.now();

    // these next three lines shouldn't affect displayMat
    cap.read(srcMat);
    cv.cvtColor(srcMat, grayMat, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    // if this line is commented out, the effect goes away
    cv.HoughCircles(grayMat, circlesMat, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 45, 75, 40, 0, 0);

    // this ought to simply create a new matrix and draw it
    let displayMat = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC1);
    cv.imshow('canvasOutput', displayMat);

    const delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
    setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably `displayMat` is created in memory place where some image processing was done with `HoughCircles()` or something. That memory was released and became available for allocating new objects in it, but neither its freeing nor new `Mat` creation did not clear that memory block.

So just clean the `displayMat` first, as it is constructed on place of some "garbage" that left from previous operations, or use `cv.Mat.zeros()` to construct `displayMat` (`zeros()` fills the whole new matrix buffer with zeros).

```
let displayMat = cv.Mat.zeros(height, width, cv.CV_8UC1);
```